# Passing a table to a SQL Server stored procedure in Vert.x

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vert.x

Looking at the Vert.x documentation [here](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/sql/SQLConnection.html), it is possible to pass a JSON array to a stored procedure in Vert.x

However, my requirement is to pass an entire table, like you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) which converted a table to a `DataTable`, and passes along to a stored procedure.

Comment: You have a requirement. You are likely getting paid for this. Are we to expect payment for our services? You need to show effort, sample data, expected output and what you have tried and what errors you have encountered

Comment: @scsimon, I usually try to give a reproducible example. However, in this case, there really is nothing to show, since it's a "feature" I wish existed in vert.x or I am unaware of. If you know of a way to pass a table, please let me know, and I shall be grateful. I apologize, either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can describe your requirement in SQL that MSSQL can handle then in theory it should be possible, however I see that you're referencing some specific .Net API and that is not available in vert.x simply because vert.x runs on the JVM not .Net.